# How can I sort a DataGridTemplateColumn on a WPF Toolkit DataGrid?

Tags: wpf, sorting, wpftoolkit, datagridtemplatecolumn

I have a WPF Toolkit DataGrid with one DataGridTemplateColumn. I've specified in a grid attribute that I wish all columns to be sortable, but the DataGridTemplateColumn won't allow it. All other columns do allow sorting. I've even tried explicitly setting CanUserSort to true for that column, but no luck. Is it even possible to sort a template column? I've provided a custom sorter that works for all columns, but the header won't allow a sort click.

```
<Controls:DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Events}" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
                               CanUserSortColumns="True" 
                               CanUserReorderColumns="False" 
                               Sorting="DataGrid_Sorting" 
                               x:Name="EventsGrid">
                <Controls:DataGrid.Columns>
                    <Controls:DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Type" Width="42" CanUserResize="False">
                        <Controls:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <Image Source="{Binding EventTypeImage, Mode=OneWay}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Width="16"/>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </Controls:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </Controls:DataGridTemplateColumn>
                    <Controls:DataGridTextColumn Header="Source" 
                                           Binding="{Binding Source, Mode=OneWay}" />
                    <Controls:DataGridTextColumn Header="Details" MinWidth="175" 
                                           Binding="{Binding Details, Mode=OneWay}" />
                    <Controls:DataGridTextColumn Header="Timestamp" MinWidth="175"  
                                           Binding="{Binding Timestamp, Mode=OneWay}" 
                                           IsReadOnly="True"/>
                </Controls:DataGrid.Columns>
            </Controls:DataGrid>
```

Answer (score 189, accepted):

You need to set the `SortMemberPath` property on `Controls:DataGridTemplateColumn` to the name of the CLR property you want to sort on.

Comment: One word of warning. This will not automatically re-sort if you change the underlying data.

Comment: Another note: this may sound silly, but if your column does not have a Header (the title) it will also not work - clicking the header triggers the sorting. I have a column that did not need a header and I sorted this out by setting Header="   "

Comment: Working as expected

Answer (score 42):

Added `SortMemberPath="Name"` to DataGridTemplateColumn. It started sorting.

```
<data:DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Name" SortMemberPath="Name" CanUserSort="True">
```

Answer (score 16):

```
 <DataGridTemplateColumn SortMemberPath="DataDiNascita" Header="Data di nascita" IsReadOnly="True">
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <DatePicker SelectedDate="{Binding Path=DataDiNascita}"></DatePicker>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=DataDiNascita,StringFormat=\{0:dd/MM/yyyy\}}"></TextBlock>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
```